# Soldering iron tip for soldering TSSOP

Tags: soldering

I found [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145271/whats-the-easiest-way-to-solder-tssop-parts/145275#145275) regarding a good method for soldering TSSOP parts but it doesn't mention what kind of tip would be most appropriate. Is a standard chisel that comes with a decent soldering iron acceptable? [Hakko](https://www.hakko.com/english/tip_selection/work_narrow_pitches.html), for example, lists tons of other options but I have no basis for choosing one.

Comment: Probably several. A fairly chunky chisel tip (2mm)  is good for drag-soldering (across a row of leads) during assembly, but a fine point may be better for reworking shorts. Sometimes you get stuck with the tip you have, and a different tip - and technique - gets you out of trouble.

Comment: I use a mini-hoof tip cartridge (drag soldering) with my Metcal soldering system.

Comment: A big tip will better transfer the heat.  Flux is what gets the right connections made.  If retouching won't clear a fault fine braid will remive the excess solder.  We've covered this here many times before so it should be closed as a duplicate.